# PaymentInetent API shows "status": "requires_payment_method" on Stripe. How can I integrate with PaymentMethod?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a PaymentIntent for Customer. However, I get the following error

```
 "status": "requires_payment_method"
```

I suppose to fix it, i should create a PaymentMethod object separately. But how do I get it done while creating the PaymentIntent. I understand that you can pass the id of created PaymentMethod. But i am not sure how this can integrated with my API.
Shared below is my code:

```
stripe_charge_response = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
          amount: amount_cents,
          currency: candidate.candidate_country[candidate.country.to_s.to_sym][:currency],
          customer: customer.id,
          statement_descriptor_suffix: "EON to Stripe test",
          on_behalf_of: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
          transfer_data: {
            destination: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
          },
        }, stripe_version: '2019-12-03',)
```

Can someone please suggest me the right approach for it?
Thanks in advance.

[image: error snippet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PaymentIntents keep track of the intents to pay for a charge. When the intent is created it’s status is `requires_payment_method` which means that a payment method is missing to complete this payment. You can learn more about the lifecycle of Payment Intents [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents). To collect payment details in a PCI compliant manner, you can use [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js). Stripe has a client-side library called Stripe.js that offers a set of products called Elements. These Elements are UI components that are used to collect secure payment information. You as the developer choose the Element that best fits your business needs.

The recommendation is to use their [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element). The Payment Element offers an embedded UI component for you to accept many Payment Methods securely with one integration. Depending on where your customer is, it dynamically sorts the Payment Method to optimize conversion, adjusts input fields automatically for different Payment Methods, validates inputs to reduce friction for card payments. You can start with this integration [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=ruby).